# counting values within groups

Tags: python, pandas

How can I count all characters='Guest' and all characters='Stranger' for each year,and if number of guest is greater then number of strangers define a year 'strange year' or 'guest year' respectively

```
g=titles.head()


name       type     character   n
Homo       actor    Guests      22.0
Ramon      actor    Owner       NaN
'El Guisa' actor    Bailaor     25.0
'El Viti'  actor    Cantaor     20.0
Murray     actor    Himself     NaN
```

Comment: Please post a sample DataFrame (not an image), what the desired output is for that sample, and what you have tried.

Comment: Here are [the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

Assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]:
   year character
0  2010    Guests
1  2010  Stranger
2  2010  Stranger
3  2011    Guests
4  2011    Guests
5  2011  Stranger
```

Option 1:

```
In [59]: df.groupby('year')['character'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
Out[59]:
year
2010    Stranger
2011      Guests
Name: character, dtype: object
```

Option 2:

```
In [61]: df.groupby('year')['character'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().nlargest(1)).reset_index()
Out[61]:
   year   level_1  character
0  2010  Stranger          2
1  2011    Guests          2
```